# ephemeral-ephemeral ECDH and MITM attack

Tags: diffie-hellman, attack

ephemeral-ephemeral ECDH is it susceptible to MITM attack ? if yes, can you please give me a detailed answer ( Workflow that can be followed by the attacker) and how we can prevent this attack (static-ephemeral or we can keep ephemeral-ephemeral and change some parameters)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: MITM on ECDH works just as [on DH in general](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26669/what-is-a-man-in-the-middle-attack-for-instance-in-diffie-hellman). The question about prevention seems to be answered e.g. [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/diffie-hellman-and-man-in-the-middle-attacks). Do those leave anything unanswered?